# How do Eagle-Men hunt?

Tags: food, humanoid, ecology

The eagle-men are a race of aquiline creatures found in the wilderness. They are flightless and wingless creatures about 4ft in height, with legs like an eagle, a body partway between humanoid and aquiline, human arms, and a reptilian/humanoid head with long whiskers. They are intelligent, but solitary, and relatively rare in the temperate forests they inhabit. They tend to avoid human-populated areas. They are carnivorous, with little tolerance for vegetables

Based on the above information, how would they hunt for their food?

Comment: How do eagle-men hunt? Probably the same way as eagle-women. :-)

Comment: Some physiology questions.. these long whiskers.. do they have any purpose ? It would help to have a raw sketch of its head.. also I wonder if this animal has 6 limbs.. it has both wings and arms. Long arms ?

Comment: @Goodies It only has arms, and I've edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Probably a lot like Ornimegalonyx**

[image]

There were once giant ground owls on Cuba, before humans. They were too large too fly and had long legs.

Wikipedia has this to say about their diet and hunting habits. (Its not much)

> The Cuban giant owl is believed to have preyed principally on large rodents including Capromys, Geocapromys, and Macrocapromys (the size of modern nutria or capybara) and the ground sloths Cubanocnus, Miocnus, Mesocnus, and Megalocnus.[4] It was probably an ambush predator that would pounce on unsuspecting prey with its crushing talons.

Comment: +1 for the size comparison image alone. That's a masterwork of graphic design, right there.

Answer (score 3):

Observation 1: they're solitary. This probably limits their intelligence, and *drastically* reduces the opportunities for tool use. Really, you need a society to develop decent tools and fancy materials (like woven fabrics or tanned leather), because it is very hard for ideas to be shared and improved upon without interaction with other intelligent folk.

This means they probably hunt with their own natural weapons. They're unlikely to have developed tools that are more effective than those.

Observation 2: they've got "eagle" legs, but they're flightless.

There is a bird of prey that kicks and stomps its victims to death: the [secretarybird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretarybird).

[image: Secretarybird]

It does fly around, but those loooong legs aren't just for show, and are suitably equipped with long pointy sharp talons. They can hunt things like snakes, by kicking them repeatedly in the head whilst keeping their body well back out of reach. Here's a tame one play-murdering a toy snake:

[image: Secretary bird hunting]

(gif found randomly on the internet, unsure of original source)

Your bird(ish) peeps won't be using wings to balance with, but they do have arms. The might even use sticks to help balance, or to brace against when doing longer or higher kicks.

Small prey get a <s>boot</s> talon to the head and probably die pretty much instantly. Larger prey probably get kicked in the abdomen, or maybe in the inside hind thigh or inside upper arm or foreleg, places where there are big blood vessels close to the surface, and will probably bleed to death over a few minutes. Odds are that they won't tackle larger prey at all, as that would be too dangerous and they don't work co-operatively. They natural weapons would do an excellent job of fending off would-be predators, though.

Absent the ability to descend from the air onto their prey, they'll either have to be stealthy ambush predators, or they'll be able to sprint like an ostrich and run their prey down and trample it to death.

Comment: Secretary birds seem to have no trouble running, like other answers claim. [Check it out.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKGDytUcApQ)

Comment: @Daron its funny that people think that bird legs wouldn't be good for running around on. I mean, ostriches exist, and all flightless birds still gotta get around somehow.

Comment: I imagine it is from watching songbirds hopping around the garden.

Answer (score 2):

With eagle legs, they probably won't be able to run very quickly, right? I'd imagine their balance being a bit funny when it comes to waddling across a field after an antelope or something.

Traps would be ideal for them, though I think bows and arrows would be better. They could find high ground and aim down at their pray, which is basically how eagles hunt - except in the eagle's case, he is the arrow, shooting down from the sky at the pray.

Answer (score 1):

> They are intelligent

They will hunt just like humanity always did: with whatever tools are available, from flint to guns. Possibly with traps too.

Specially since they are small and solitary, they need to leverage technology if they are to match human efficiency in hunting.

We became intelligent when we mastered fire, because it can break down some nutrients - allowing us to use less energy for digestion and therefore more energy for thinking. If your eagle folk can't do that, then they should be no smarter than chimps, possibly being dumber. In that case they would hunt like apes do: "I'm going to chase that furry thing and pull its limbs off".